# Deploying Meteor + Angular2 app to Heroku

Tags: mongodb, meteor, heroku, angular, angular2-meteor

I have an app I'm writing using Meteor, Angular2 (using the [angular-meteor](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor) package), Typescript, and MongoDB. I'm trying to put it up on Heroku and running into difficulties. I'm using this [meteor buildpack](https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor). I'm not sure whether the problems are with Meteor, Heroku, or Angular2, though I suspect it's something Heroku isn't configuring correctly for Angular2. The site is at http://alfred-zahner.herokuapp.com/ and the error I'm getting is:

> EXCEPTION: No provider for t! (e -> t)

I've checked the Heroku logs and there is no sign of trouble there. Part of my problem is that I can't see what `t` and `e` are, as someone (Heroku?) is uglifying the JavaScript. I'm not really sure how to proceed in debugging this.

One way to solve this problem would be to figure out and fix the error, but I'd be happy if there's a better build pack, or even a better (must be free!) hosting environment that I could be using.

**Edit**

It's not Heroku's problem. The same thing happens when deploying to Meteor's built in deployment testing (`meteor deploy site.meteor.com`). If I deploy using `meteor deploy --debug site.meteor.com`, however, it works, so Angular2 has some problem with the extra processing that happens when Meteor prepares an app for production.

Comment: Have you tried pushing the app to Modulus instead? https://modulus.io/

Comment: As far as I can tell there's no free plan on Modulus.

Comment: Figure anything out on this? I'm deploying to bare metal and running into the same issue. It seems like it may be a problem with minification screwing with the parameter names that Angular's dependency injection system uses but I can't figure out a fix.

Comment: @joshperry See my answer below. For Heroku, it seems like you should be able to edit the buildpack to build with debug enabled. However, I tried that and Heroku timed out my deploy after one hour. If you want to try it, I forked https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor to https://github.com/twastvedt/heroku-buildpack-meteor and just added a `--debug` to the `meteor build` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [angular2-meteor Github](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/145#issuecomment-182857381) I found out that this is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6380) with Angular 2 in particular, when using UglifyJS. For now, it seems the only solution is to use `meteor deploy --debug`. I'm planning to just use that on meteor's built in hosting until Angular 2 plays nicely.

Comment: This is exactly how I ended up working around the problem as well. Thank you for your response!